# How to fill strings in a 2D char array of C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Trying to implement `strtok`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* my_strtok (char* arg_string, const char* arg_delimeter)
{
    char** after_tokenization      = (char**) malloc (sizeof(char) * 1000);
    char*  hold_chars_of_one_group = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char) * strlen(arg_string));

    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;

    while (arg_string[i])
    {
        if (arg_string[i] != *arg_delimeter)
        {
            hold_chars_of_one_group[k] = arg_string[i];
            k++;
        }
        else
        {
            after_tokenization[j][0] = hold_chars_of_one_group;

            j++;
            k = 0;
        }
        i++;
    }

    return after_tokenization;
}


int main(void)
{
    char*p = my_strtok ("qwerty,asdf,shizuka,sharma", ",");
    return 0;
}
```

By putting printfs I can see that seg fault is in this line:

`after_tokenization[j][0] = hold_chars_of_one_group;`

Before crashing j's value is shown to be 2. Sufficient memory has been allocated to both arrays, then what is the way to push values in a 2D char array of C?

Why am I getting seg fault over there? What's the way out?

Comment: (Possibly) unrelated, but *conceptually* its initialization is incorrect. You allocate `sizeof(char) * 1000`, This should be `sizeof(char *)`. (Possibly unrlated because it should be enough memory for your test string anyway.)

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings.

Comment: Oh and the return value should be `char **`, and the same in `main` :)

Comment: @RadLexus thanks, I will correct that.

Comment: @RadLexus - It's not unrelated. That *is* the cause of the segfault. You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @StoryTeller: are you sure? Not behind my desktop now, but I thought it couldn't be because it still makes lots of memory available. Even if the pointers are 8 bytes long, it could store 125 entries - much longer than OP's entire string. It ought to store just 3. (Which draws my attention to this: what about the first?)

Comment: @StoryTeller: ... if you can pinpoint the exact point of failure, go ahead :)

Comment: @RadLexus - At first it seemed like a simple out of bound buffer. Now it's just derefencing an invalid pointer, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe their are some problems with you code:

- You are typecasting return of `malloc()`. Their is no need for that in C. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).
- Allocation for `after_tokenization` is wrong. You need to allocate space for `char *` pointers, not `char` characters. it needs to be allocated like this:

  ```
  char** after_tokenization = malloc (sizeof(char*) * 1000);
  ```
- Return of `malloc()` needs to be checked, as it can return `NULL`.
- This line:

  ```
  after_tokenization[j][0] = hold_chars_of_one_group;
  ```

  is dangerous, as you are not really copying `hold_chars_of_one_group` into your array. You need to `malloc()` some space for this, then `strcpy()` it into the array. Their is multiple methods for this.

  Your current code just overwrites the address of previous pointers added. Their also no need for `[j][0]`, as you only need to copy into a pointer location `[j]`.
- `strtok()` can take multiple delimiters, but your code only handles `1`. This isn't really a problem, just something to consider.
- `my_strtok()` returns `char *`, but you are returning `char **` in this function. You need to change this to `char **my_strtok()`.
- You also need to `free()` any allocated memory at the end.

These points will help improve your code, and make it functional.

### Here is some example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXSTR 1000

char **mystrtok(char *arg_string, const char *arg_delimeter);

int main(void) {
    char **result = NULL;

    result = mystrtok("qwerty,asdf,shizuka,sharma", ",");

    /* printing and freeing strings */
    for (size_t i = 0; result[i] != NULL; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", result[i]);
        free(result[i]);
        result[i] = NULL;
    }

    free(result);
    result = NULL;

    return 0;
}

char **mystrtok(char *arg_string, const char *arg_delimeter) {
    char **after_tokenization = NULL;
    char *group_char = NULL;
    size_t arrsize = MAXSTR, slen, count = 0, numstr = 0, delim_flag;

    /* allocation of array, with error checking */
    after_tokenization = malloc(arrsize * sizeof * after_tokenization);
    if (!after_tokenization) {
        printf("Cannot allocate %zu spaces for pointers\n", arrsize);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    slen = strlen(arg_string);

    /* allocation of buffer, with error checking */
    group_char = malloc(slen+1);
    if (!group_char) {
        printf("Cannot allocate %zu bytes for string\n", slen+1);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (size_t ch = 0; arg_string[ch]; ch++) {
        delim_flag = 0;

        /* loop to handle multiple delimeters */
        for (size_t del = 0; arg_delimeter[del]; del++) {
            if (arg_string[ch] == arg_delimeter[del]) {
                delim_flag = 1;
            }
        }

        /* no delim found, add to buffer */
        if (!delim_flag) {
            group_char[count++] = arg_string[ch];
            group_char[count] = '\0';

        /* only add if delim found and buffer is not NULL */
        } else if (delim_flag && *group_char) {

            /* make space in array */
            after_tokenization[numstr] = malloc(slen+1);
            if (!after_tokenization[numstr]) {
                printf("Cannot allocate %zu bytes for string\n", slen+1);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            /* copy buffer into array */
            strcpy(after_tokenization[numstr], group_char);

            numstr++;
            count = 0;

            /* clear buffer */
            memset(group_char, '\0', slen+1);
        }
    }

    /* for last string found */
    if (*group_char) {
        after_tokenization[numstr] = malloc(slen+1);
        if (!after_tokenization[numstr]) {
            printf("Cannot allocate %zu bytes for string\n", slen+1);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        strcpy(after_tokenization[numstr], group_char);
        numstr++;
    }

    /* free buffer, not longer needed */
    free(group_char);

    /* add sentinel, just in case */
    after_tokenization[numstr] = NULL;

    /* return char** at the end */
    return after_tokenization;
}
```

**Note:** This is just some code I wrote, and it can be heavily improved. It just shows the idea.

Answer (score 2):

```
after_tokenization[j][0] = hold_chars_of_one_group;
```

Even if you allocated enough memory for `after_tokenization`. The **pointer** at `after_tokenization[j]` isn't initialized. It contains an unspecifed address. So when you dereference it by applying the subscript operator `[0]`, it's undefiend behavior.

And that is most probably the cause of your crash.

Answer (score 2):

You need an array of pointers to hold the strings, so it should be:

```
char** after_tokenization      = (char**) malloc (sizeof(char*) * 1000);
```

and `after_tokenization[j][0]` is meaningless because `after_tokenization[j]` is just a pointer, you haven't allocate memory for it. Here is the modified version according to your code.

```
char** my_strtok (char* arg_string, const char* arg_delimeter)
{
    char** after_tokenization      = (char**) malloc (sizeof(char*) * 1000);
    char*  hold_chars_of_one_group = (char*) calloc(strlen(arg_string) + 1, sizeof(char)); // use calloc to fill the memory with bytes of value zero.

    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;

    while (arg_string[i])
    {
        if (arg_string[i] != *arg_delimeter)
        {
            hold_chars_of_one_group[k] = arg_string[i];
            k++;
        }
        else
        {
            hold_chars_of_one_group[k] = 0;
            after_tokenization[j] = hold_chars_of_one_group;
            hold_chars_of_one_group += k+1;

            j++;
            k = 0;
        }
        i++;
    }

    // last one
    if (hold_chars_of_one_group[0] != 0) {
        hold_chars_of_one_group[k] = 0;
        after_tokenization[j] = hold_chars_of_one_group;
    }

    /*for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", after_tokenization[i]);
    } */


    return after_tokenization;
}
```

Comment: `... = calloc(strlen(arg_string), ...` should be `...= calloc(strlen(arg_string) + 1, ...`.

Comment: @alk indeed. Fixed that

Answer (score 0):

fix like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char** my_strtok (char* arg_string, const char* arg_delimeter){
    size_t len = strlen(arg_string);
    char **after_tokenization     = malloc(sizeof(char*) * ((len + 1)/2 +1));//max token + 1 (+1 for NULL)
    char *hold_chars_of_one_group = malloc(len + 1);

    int i, j, k;
    i = j = k = 0;

    while (*arg_string){
        if (*arg_string != *arg_delimeter){
            hold_chars_of_one_group[k++] = *arg_string;
        } else  {
            hold_chars_of_one_group[k++] = 0;
            after_tokenization[j++] = &hold_chars_of_one_group[i];
            i = k;
        }
        ++arg_string;
    }
    hold_chars_of_one_group[k] = 0;
    after_tokenization[j++] = &hold_chars_of_one_group[i];
    after_tokenization[j] = NULL;//NULL is terminator

    return after_tokenization;
}

int main(void){
    char **p = my_strtok ("anisha,kaul,shizuka,sharma", ",");
    for(char **temp = p; *temp; ++temp){
        printf ("-%s-\n", *temp);
    }
    free(*p);
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```